# Issue with Scaffold Messenger: The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i hope you can help me. I'm trying to use the new way to show a SnackBar with ScaffoldMessenger instead of Scaffold. When i try to run this, i got this issue:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: showSnackBar(Instance of 'SnackBar')
```

And this is my code:

```
import 'package:cab_rider/screens/loginpage.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/widgets/TaxiButton.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegistrationPage extends StatelessWidget {

  static const String id = 'register';

  var NombresController = TextEditingController();
  var ApePaternoController = TextEditingController();
  var ApeMaternoController= TextEditingController();
  var EmailController = TextEditingController();
  var TelefonoController = TextEditingController();
  var PasswordController = TextEditingController();
  var Password2Controller = TextEditingController();


  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  void showSnack(String title){

    final snackbar = SnackBar(
        content: Text(title, textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,),)
    );
    scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
    
  }

  

  void registerUser() async {

    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: EmailController.text,
          password: PasswordController.text

      );
      if(userCredential != null){
        print ('reg lista');
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 70,),
                Image(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  image: AssetImage('images/logo_pana.png'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 40,),
                Text('Crear una cuenta de gruero(a)',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontFamily: 'Brand-Bold'),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      //Nombres
                      TextField(
                        controller: NombresController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Nombres',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 10.0
                            )
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                      //ApePaterno
                      TextField(
                        controller: ApePaternoController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Apellido Paterno',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 10.0
                            )
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                      //ApeMaterno
                      TextField(
                        controller: ApeMaternoController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Apellido Materno',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 10.0
                            )
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                      //Email
                      TextField(
                        controller: EmailController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Correo',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 10.0
                            )
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),


                      //Telefono
                      TextField(
                        controller: TelefonoController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Número de tel\éfono',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 10.0
                            )
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                      //Contraseña
                      TextField(
                        controller: PasswordController,
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Contraseña',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 10.0
                            )
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      //Confirmar Contraseña
                      TextField(
                        controller: Password2Controller,
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Reingresar Contraseña',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 10.0
                            )
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),

                      TaxiButton(
                          title: 'REGISTRAR',
                          color: Colors.deepPurple,
                          onPressed: (){

                            //verificar datos
                            if(NombresController.text.length < 3){
                              showSnack('Nombre demasiado corto.');
                              return;
                            }
                            if(TelefonoController.text.length < 9){
                              showSnack('Número inválido.');
                              return;
                            }
                            if(EmailController.text.contains('@')){
                              showSnack('Ingrese un correo válido.');
                              return;
                            }
                            if(PasswordController.text.length < 8){
                              showSnack('La contraseña debe tener mínimo 8 carácteres.');
                              return;
                            }

                            registerUser();

                          }
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, LoginPage.id, (route) => false);
                    },
                    child: Text('¿Ya tienes una cuenta?. Ingresa aquí!'))

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've read some of answers of the same issue, but the version that they used, wasn't the lattest one. Flutter changed the old way to show snackbars, to ScaffoldMessenger, i'm very noob.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ScaffoldMessenger`, you can change from

```
return Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
```

To

```
 return ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      child: Scaffold(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class RegistrationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'register';

  var NombresController = TextEditingController();
  var ApePaternoController = TextEditingController();
  var ApeMaternoController = TextEditingController();
  var EmailController = TextEditingController();
  var TelefonoController = TextEditingController();
  var PasswordController = TextEditingController();
  var Password2Controller = TextEditingController();

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  void showSnack(String title) {
    final snackbar = SnackBar(
        content: Text(
      title,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
      ),
    ));
    scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
  }

  void registerUser() async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: EmailController.text, password: PasswordController.text);
      if (userCredential != null) {
        print('reg lista');
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 70,
                  ),
                  Image(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: 100.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Crear una cuenta de gruero(a)',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontFamily: 'Brand-Bold'),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //Nombres
                        TextField(
                          controller: NombresController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Nombres',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10.0)),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        //ApePaterno
                        TextField(
                          controller: ApePaternoController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Apellido Paterno',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10.0)),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),

                        //ApeMaterno
                        TextField(
                          controller: ApeMaternoController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Apellido Materno',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10.0)),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),

                        //Email
                        TextField(
                          controller: EmailController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Correo',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10.0)),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),

                        //Telefono
                        TextField(
                          controller: TelefonoController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Número de tel\éfono',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10.0)),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),

                        //Contraseña
                        TextField(
                          controller: PasswordController,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Contraseña',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10.0)),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        //Confirmar Contraseña
                        TextField(
                          controller: Password2Controller,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Reingresar Contraseña',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10.0)),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                            child: Text('REGISTRAR'),
                            //color: Colors.deepPurple,
                            onPressed: () {
                              //verificar datos
                              if (NombresController.text.length < 3) {
                                showSnack('Nombre demasiado corto.');
                                return;
                              }
                              if (TelefonoController.text.length < 9) {
                                showSnack('Número inválido.');
                                return;
                              }
                              if (EmailController.text.contains('@')) {
                                showSnack('Ingrese un correo válido.');
                                return;
                              }
                              if (PasswordController.text.length < 8) {
                                showSnack(
                                    'La contraseña debe tener mínimo 8 carácteres.');
                                return;
                              }

                              registerUser();
                            })
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        //Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, LoginPage.id, (route) => false);
                      },
                      child: Text('¿Ya tienes una cuenta?. Ingresa aquí!'))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: RegistrationPage(),
    );
  }
}
```